# Redirect user from a React component in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

In a Rails view I have a react component which is a form.

When a user submits the form, I need to redirect him somewhere else.

I don't use react-router because this react component is basically standalone in the rails app and I failed using the controller to do the direction.

Do you have an idea of how I should do that?

Comment: When do you want the redirect to happen - in React, before Rails deals with the form, or in Rails, after the data is received? If you don't mind, Rails is probably the best option!

Comment: Thanks for replying! Basically, the React form sends the form data to the controller and if the React form receives a 200 status code from the controller, then it means the form data was valid and the user can be redirected. Where and how should the redirect be done?

Comment: rails controller should return a `redirect_link` attribute and react side will know where to go, e.g. `{status: 200, redirect_link: '/home'}`  or `{status: 400, redirect_link: '/users/sign_in'}`

Comment: I suspect Lam Phan's suggestion is the way to go: return the code and redirection info from Rails for React to use.

Comment: That is more or less what I did, but how would you make that redirect happen? I hacked it by passing the link into a link tag and simulating a click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to simulate a click - return a JSON object from Rails containing the URL as a property, then call `location.href` in your JS on success, passing that URL.